# Jquery get list value without parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, parent

I have this code that for now creates a Alert() with the value of that list item.
Now when i click a list item that has another list item as parent. it will alert() them both.

```
$("#nav li").click(function() {
    $LiValue = this.value;
    alert($LiValue);
});
```

Example. here is the HTML

```
<li value="1">Home</li>
  <li value="2">Information
    <ul class="subs">
    <li value="3">History</li>
    <li value="4">Present</li>
    <li value="5">Future</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Now when i click on list item "Information" it will return with value 2
When i click on list item "Present" it will return value 4 and then 2.

How can i only return the list item i click on and not the parent?

--------->>>> SOLVED!! (can't accept answer yet)
Thank you all for helping me. i will accept the answer as soon as i can. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events in JavaScript naturally bubble up the DOM tree, from child elements to their ancestors. You can stop this behavior by [stopping the event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation).

```
$("#nav li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $LiValue = this.value;
    alert($LiValue);
});
```

Comment: The [jQuery event API docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) also includes a write-up on this, as well as other useful [event methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Answer (score 2):

The fix to your problem is **stopPropagation().** The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) tells you that this function "Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event."

Basically, the event will not be fired for any of the parent elements. In order to use this method, handle the first parameter that your click function provides you. Then you call the method inside the function. Your method should look like this

```
$("#nav li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $LiValue = this.value;
    alert($LiValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#nav li").click(function(e) {
    $LiValue = this.value;
    alert($LiValue);
    return false;
});
```

or try to add `return false`.

Explanation : The difference is that `return false;` takes things a bit further in that it also prevents that event from propagating (or "bubbling up") the DOM. The you-may-not-know-this bit is that whenever an event happens on an element, that event is triggered on every single parent element as well. 
So in other words:

```
function() {
  return false;
}
```

// IS EQUAL TO

```
function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

see this  [link](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/) for further explanation

Comment: Heya, this is great that you've answered... it's not really my field so I can't tell if it's a good solution. A bit of explanation for why your suggestion would work, would go a long way toward helping with that. Don't forget - lots of newbies come to Stack Overflow all the time, and we could learn a few things from you. What may be obvious to you, is often not to somebody new in the field ;)

Comment: @Taryn East, heyo too, thanks for your suggestion,answer editted. Will try to add more explanation on my answer, rather than to go on fast craving for some points.haha thanks